# Pointers in new Array() causing problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers

can someone explain to me why using `new Array()` and filling it with more Array (**a Matrix**) generated in the same way, causes that in the end there is only one reference?

For example, if a create a matrix of 5x4 and fill it with zeros.

```
var matrix = new Array(5).fill( new Array(3).fill(0) )
// 0  0  0
// 0  0  0
// 0  0  0
// 0  0  0
// 0  0  0
```

and if a change **ONE** element, it affects the entire row, why?

```
matrix[3][1] = 5
//This is what I get
// 0  5  0 
// 0  5  0
// 0  5  0
// 0  5  0
// 0  5  0
```

> The snippet

```js
var matrix = new Array(5).fill( new Array(3).fill(0) )
console.log("matrix before...")
matrix.forEach(row => console.log(row))

matrix[3][1] = 5
console.log("matrix after...")
matrix.forEach(row => console.log(row))
```

Comment: Yes, you have only created one instance of the inner array.

Comment: To get multiple instances for each row, you could try this construct -> `var matrix = new Array(5).fill(0).map(() => new Array(3).fill(0))`  or `Array.from(new Array(5),()=>new Array(3).fill(0));`

Answer (score 1):

`new Array(3).fill(0)` is evaluated once, as an argument, and its return value--one particular array--is copied into each element of the outer array. You need to instead use a loop that calls `new Array(3).fill(0)` 5 times or put it in a lambda with a function that will call the lambda for each element of the outer array, eg:

```
Array.from(new Array(5), () => new Array(3).fill(0));
```

(expanded from Keith's comment)